# php5-common php5-json deadlock

Tags: php, dpkg

I am trying to install php5_5.5.6 on my debian machine. I downloaded php5-cgi,php5-fpm,php5-common,php5-json,libjson-c as per the depends list on debain site http://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5 .
 When i try to install php5-common, i get error saying php5-json is not installed. When i try to install php5-json, i get an error saying "Package php5-common which provides phpapi-20121212 is not configured yet." How can i overcome this deadlock?

I dont have apt-get facility, so need to download manually  and install the packages.

Thanks.

Comment: download the .deb from debian.org and just use dpkg then if you don't have apt-get though why do you not have apt-get its debian standard? if you don't have it then just install it.

Comment: why not using `apt-get`?

Comment: Its my client machine which is in a private network.. So cant use apt-get.